# How to create an element on button click?

Tags: angularjs

I want to create dynamically an element when I click on a button. Do I have to use `ng-click` or a directive for that?

Here is a [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Elfayer/w2x8ukz2/) of what I'm trying to achieve using jQuery :

**HTML:**

```
<button id="myButton">Click Me</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#myButton").on("click", function() {
    $("#container").append('<div class="box"></div>');
});
```

Also, here is a base **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Elfayer/5r7pem4e/)**, of what I have so far, to work on if you want for an angularjs solution.

**Warn:**

- Please avoid a solution with a controller using `ng-repeat`. The code above is a simplified example. The created elements won't be as a list, because I'll attach a drag directive to them.

Comment: you dont have to use ng-click, but you can.

Comment: I can't visualise how to do that. I'm fairly new at angularjs and still have some problem to know what to use in which case and how to use it.

Comment: You should research how to properly use directives. You are right that a directive is the correct solution, you just need to follow through and add a link function with a controller and a template.

Comment: I've read the full documentation on Directives and watched a video on youtube of about an hour on it. Still, it seems to have a lot of possibilities, and I wanted to have some examples to look at in this case. I'll take a deeper look at link property. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I have to use ng-click or a directive for that?

To create new element I would use [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile). Any DOM manipulations I strongly recommend to do in directives only. You can trigger appending process through `ng-click` directive or to use `bind` like:

```
 element.bind("click", function(e){
      // do stuff here
   });
```

Something like that:

```
 demo.directive("boxCreator", function($compile){   
      return{
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope , element){        
           element.bind("click", function(e){

            var childNode = $compile('<button ng-click="doStuff()" >new button</button>')(scope)
            element.parent().append(childNode);                   
           });

            scope.doStuff = function(){                   
              // do stuff
            }
        }
    }
   });
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fess81/axq5vu41/)**</kbd>

Comment: This is a solid answer - I would only recommend tying a template into this that joins the "click me" button, and the new box getting appended to the container so that you can leverage ng-click instead.

Comment: I don't understand this line : `var childNode = $compile('<button >new button</button>')(scope)`

Comment: Is it better do use a directive to `bind` or a controller would do the trick ? (Just asking for best practice)

Comment: @Elfayer the `$compile` tells to angular that new DOM element is created and will notify angular to run digest cycle on new created element. Take a look on `ng-click` I added to button template. For sure you can use `$compile` in controller but its not good practice.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsbin.com/cuciyu/2/edit

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive("addDiv", function($compile){   
          return{
            restrict: 'AE',
            link: function(scope , element,attr){        
               element.bind("click", function(e){ 
               var container =   angular.element(document.querySelector("#container"));
               var childNode = $compile('<div class="box">BOX DIV</div>')(container);
               container.append(childNode);

               });
            }
        };
       });

    app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){


    });
```

**HTML:**

```
  <body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <button add-div>Click Me</button>
        <div id="container"></div>
      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: DOM manipulation in the controller is bad practice. It's even worse that you aren't using the $document service. Finally, it doesn't allow him to add more than one box.

Comment: @Fourth agree but that is answer for Elfayer question