# Add elements dynamically in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sorry, maybe it's stupid question but i'm still learning.

I want to add some elements dynamically on a button click in my view.its working fine for me but i have some doubts.because i am learning angularJs i want to know there is any better way to do these things.

1.from documentation i understood angularJS is entirely different from jquery so in this example i used the same concept which we are used with jquery so i want to know if there is any better way to do this.

2.i can able to access dom element using $element in controller but am unable to access the same inside click event

```
app.controller('SalesController',function($scope,$element) {
  //here we can access like this
  $element[0].getElementsByClassName("classSub")[0];
  $scope.Change = function () {
    //we can access variables like this
    var temp= $scope.salesData
    //but this code will not work here
    $element[0].getElementsByClassName("classSub")[0];      
  }
});
```

3.innerHTML and append is not working with getElementsByClassName but it will work with document.querySelector

```
$scope.Change = function () {
  if($scope.salesData%2==0) {
    bindChart="";
    bindChart=bindChart+"<div class='sub1'></div>";    

    //these code will not add the div dynamically
    //document.getElementsByClassName("classSub"[0].innerHTML=bindChart;
    //document.getElementsByClassName("classSub")[0].append(bindChart);
    //document.querySelector( '.classSub' ).append(bindChart);

    //this will work
    document.querySelector( '.classSub' ).innerHTML=bindChart;
  } else {
    bindChart="";
    bindChart=bindChart+"<div class='sub2'></div>";
    document.querySelector( '.classSub' ).innerHTML=bindChart;
  } 
  $scope.salesData++;
}
```

can anyone explain what is the problem... I am a beginner in angularJS

[Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/renjithgovind/c4gc01tr/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an element on button click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183186/how-to-create-an-element-on-button-click)

Comment: Can you provide your HTML?

Comment: @Mistalis: I added one link in this question please chek

Comment: You may wish to examine the `parse` directive. This is useful when you are altering the DOM programmatically. Not sure this is your issue.

Comment: @GROX13: can u explain the solution for 2 and 3

Comment: [user3501613](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3501613/user3501613) I don't understand your second question. It works when I try your Fiddler example `$element[0].getElementsByClassName("classSub")[0];` returns: `<div class="classSub"><div class="sub1"></div></div>` inside change function and returns `<div class="classSub"></div>` outside.

Answer (score 0):

### I have UPDATED my answer from your comment:

Just declare `$scope.salesData = [];` in your controller, and use this code in HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="sale in salesData" ng-class="{sub1: sale.n == 0, sub2: sale.n == 1}"></div>
<button type="button" ng-click="salesData.push({n:salesData.length % 2})">Click Me!</button>
```

When you click your button, it creates a new `div` according to your condition (odd or even).

Forked your fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/on56nfL5/).

---

### How it works?

- `$scope.salesData` is an empty array.
- When you click the button, it pushs an object in `salesData`.
- This object as a value (`n`) switching between 0 and 1 (odd/even).
- [**`ng-repeat`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) will create a `div` **for each** element in this array.
- [**`ng-class`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) will style this `div` depending of n value (odd/even).

Comment: sorry u are mistaken,, i need to append two different div according to that condition(odd or even)

Comment: that code is working fine but i think that is not the proper way to do that thing in angularJS,,

Comment: Updated my answer :)